# What's wrong with my copy here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, copy, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to copy a file from my application bundle to my app's documents directory. I'm getting an error, "Cocoa Error 262". What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreData.sqlite"];
NSURL *initialURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CoreData" ofType:@"sqlite"]];

NSError *error = nil;

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[initialURL absoluteString]]) {
    NSLog(@"Original does not exist. \nPath: %@", [initialURL absoluteString]);
}  

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL absoluteString]]) {
    NSLog(@"Destination file does not exist. \nPath: %@", [storeURL absoluteString]);

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:initialURL toURL:storeURL error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is you're initializing a URL with a plain old file path.

```
NSURL *initialURL = 
    [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CoreData" 
                                                         ofType:@"sqlite"]];
```

Use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is

`NSFileReadUnsupportedSchemeError 
Read error because the specified URL scheme is unsupported`

which I believe would mean one of your paths is not forming correctly. perhaps write these paths to the log and see if they are coming out as you expect them to.

Comment: What is the correct scheme, and where did you get this information from?

Comment: Don't use +URLWithString: unless you want to build up the entire "file:///path/to/file" path. But why would you when +fileURLWithPath: does that for you.

Comment: got the info from [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html) correct scheme pretty much means how your url is formatted.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem, although to be honest, I'm not sure what it was. I have to go over the working code again, but here it is:

```
    NSError *error = nil;


NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", @"CoreData", @"sqlite"]];

//if file does not exist in document directory, gets original from mainbundle and copies it to documents.

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSString *defaultFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CoreData" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:defaultFilePath toPath:filePath error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I suspect that the path to the application directory was incorrect, given that the body of the generated `applicationDocumentsDirectory` looks different than the method used for the value of the `documentsDorectory` variable shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Error 262 is defined in FoundationErrors.h to be NSFileReadUnsupportedSchemeError.

I'd suggest that you use NSLog() to write out the literal values of the two URLs that you're using and make sure that they are file:// URLs and that they look complete.